# How to pass array from admin controller to grid block

Tags: module, blocks, admin-controller

What I need is pass some json data to grid block and display it in a grid. I have created admin module and successfully recieve json data. But I dont know how to pass json to block.

```
class Somecompany_Modulename_Adminhtml_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function pollAction() {  
        $json = $this->_getCurlData();
        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess($json);         
        $this->loadLayout();    
        return $this->renderLayout();
    }
    private function _getCurlData() {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('print_id');
        $url = "https://my.sample.url";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $json;
    }
```

}

How to pass this data to block?

Tried this. But I think there should be another way.

```
Mage::register('name',$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
 Mage::register('json_data', $json);
```

getting the data in block

```
if ( Mage::registry('json_data') )
 {

    $data=Mage::registry('json_data');
  }
```

Comment: I thought there's a better way. Thanks @Qaisar

Comment: this is the better way magento use this and also i recommended use this.

Comment: When json is huge does it cause any performance issues?

Comment: no it is not causing any issue. magento store collection in that. it is destroy after the page load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class Somecompany_Modulename_Adminhtml_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function pollAction() 
    {  
        $json = $this->_getCurlData();

        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('Your_Block')->setJsonData($json);
        return $this->renderLayout();
    }
    private function _getCurlData() 
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('print_id');
        $url = "https://my.sample.url";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $json;
    }
```

and in your block file you can access like

```
$this->getJsonData();
```